# Metric name when using absent

Tags: prometheus

I have the following query returning absent metrics:

```
(absent({__name__=~"ms_gauge.*"})) == 1
```

Which currently returns

```
1
```

How can I get the specific metric name that is absent as I'm using regex?

Comment: I don't understand, what name do you expect to see if it is absent (i.e. does not exist)? `ms_gauge.*`? And in which context, an alert?

Comment: So absent doesn't not check if a metric was ever there? If not, then I understand why It's not showing any error.

Comment: It checks that at the evaluation time, something like `now - 5 minutes ago`. If there was no metric - you have 1 (true), if there is - you get 0 (false). I think you need [absent_over_time()](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#absent_over_time) if you want to check if it has ever existed.

Comment: @newduino probably your need yo specify your problem you want to solve with your query a bit better.